# Get coefficient of friction given mass, forward force, and acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction

I'm aware that this is extremely basic but I've forgotten how to get the coefficient of friction when given a forward force and acceleration.

Can someone describe to me the algorithm for solving the following example question?

Mass = 50kg

Forward Force Acting on Mass = 100 N

Acceleration of Mass = 0.1m/s^2

Coefficient of friction?

EDIT:
Am I right in thinking it is 0.2?

Comment: Have you revisted an introductory physics textbook, or looked online at recourses like hyperphysics?

Comment: I have but I didn't see anything that regarded getting the coefficient of friction when acceleration is included. I am having somewhat of a mental-blank at the moment and just want to make sure I know the steps needed as I have a physics test later today. EDIT: My mental fog is clearing and I am beginning to realize ridiculously easy this is. I'd still like an answer to assure I am correct but I'm fairly sure I can figure this out on my own

Comment: There are two forces, the forward force and friction. The difference of these forces is the net force equal to the product of mass and acceleration. From this you get the friction force. From this divide then normal force, mg to get them friction force.

Comment: It is 0.2 correct?

Comment: Really 0.1938...., but rounding to two decimals or using g=10, you get 0.19

Comment: Use $g=9.80665$ which is the SI standard value.

Comment: Or use $g = 10 \,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ so that (a) the professor won't dock you for leaving off units and (b) so you can focus on the physics rather than messy and inconvenient numbers. Seriously, I try very hard to get my students to *stop* caring about numbers first so that they will learn to get some value out of the symbolic representation of the physics.

Answer (score 1):

Do a free body diagram and you will find for a horizontal plane that

$$ F - \mu m g = m a $$

$$ (100) - \mu (50) (9.80665) = (50) (0.1) $$

$$\boxed{ \mu = \frac{(100)-(0.1)(50)}{(50)(9.80665)} = 0.1937\ldots }$$

Comment: Ah yes.  Immediately substitute values into the starting equation and avoid the algebra necessary to separate the unknown variable.  THAT technique is why most U.S. high school students are practically algebraically illiterate.

Comment: @DavidWhite - I actually I didn't, since the final expression was already solved for $\mu$ and the substitution was the _last_ step. The difference is if I carry the symbols vs. their value around.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's 2nd law in the x-direction. There are only two forces that together equal the $ma$, and since you know one of them, it is straight forward from here.